# How to install SCO Open server in the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, google-cloud-platform

I need to install unix sco open server 5.0.5 in the cloud, does anyone have any idea how to do that?
I really hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SCO OpenServer 5.0.5 was released in 1999. I seriously doubt that it would be possible to run that old of an OS in Google Cloud. Installation would not be possible directly in the cloud. You would need to install it first to Hyper-V or VMware and then upload the VHD/VMDK.

Another issue for systems that old is the disk device drivers have assumptions about the BIOS and disk geometry. Back then 8 GB disks were large. Today a 10 GB disk is the bare minimum in most situations. Even if you could import a VHD/VMDK I do not believe it will boot. I wrote SCO OpenServer disk and RAID device drivers. Each time a new disk drive came out, we had to make changes to the disk tables to handle the new geometry, parameters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information, would there be an alternative to running some binaries from the SCO Open server in a linux distribution?